# I want four flipboxes inline and two rows. thought I followed steps i found on your site about four months ago but can't get it to work

Tags: html, css, styles, inline

I'm trying to place on a web page 4 flip boxes inline and a second row of them in the same way. But right now all i get is a single set of type and no boxes. On the boxes would be some type and on the other more type or pictures. They would flip over to reveal the other side when the mouse hovers over it. I initially got two boxes but they were on top of each other and then trying to get those two inline I lost my boxes.

I found someone's similar predicament and followed the conversation (from four months ago)and the guy who was helping provided a link to his page to show what he did and I tried to include his code on my page to get it to work but it didn't. Can anybody help?

HERE IS THE CSS

```
/* The flip box container - set the width and height to whatever you want. We have added the border
 property to demonstrate that the flip itself goes out of the box on hover (remove perspective if you don't want the 3D effect */


.flip-box {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
  perspective: 1000px; /* Remove this if you don't want the 3D effect */
}

/* This container is needed to position the front and back side */
.flip-box-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.8s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

/* Do an horizontal flip when you move the mouse over the flip box container */
.flip-box:hover .flip-box-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

/* Position the front and back side */
.flip-box-front, .flip-box-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; /* Safari */
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

/* Style the front side */
.flip-box-front {
  background-color: #bbb;
  color: black;
}

/* Style the back side */
.flip-box-back {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}


.container {
  text-align: center;
}
```

AND NOW THE HTML

HTML below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">
 {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="flip-box">
  <div class="flip-box-inner">
    <div class="flip-box-front">
      <h2>Front Side</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="flip-box-back">
      <h2>Back Side</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified the whole code below (skip this part to see results)
Step-by-step instructions:

1.Let's make the CSS external in our HTML from this:

```
<style type="text/css">
 {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

To this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

2.Making a div with class container, containing 10 flipboxes. Simply duplicating them. Introducing the grid layout to help them be inline

```
.container {
    width: 80%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Let's use automatic width of columns to 1fr - 1fraction/unit proportionally by commencting out the fixed width

```
.flip-box {
  background-color: transparent;
  /* width: 300px; */
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
  perspective: 1000px; /* Remove this if you don't want the 3D effect */
}
```

```css
/* The flip box container - set the width and height to whatever you want. We have added the border
 property to demonstrate that the flip itself goes out of the box on hover (remove perspective if you don't want the 3D effect */
body  {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.container {
    width: 80%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    margin: auto;
}
.flip-box {
  background-color: transparent;
  /* width: 300px; */
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
  perspective: 1000px; /* Remove this if you don't want the 3D effect */
}

/* This container is needed to position the front and back side */
.flip-box-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.8s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

/* Do an horizontal flip when you move the mouse over the flip box container */
.flip-box:hover .flip-box-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

/* Position the front and back side */
.flip-box-front, .flip-box-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; /* Safari */
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

/* Style the front side */
.flip-box-front {
  background-color: #bbb;
  color: black;
}

/* Style the back side */
.flip-box-back {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}


.container {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">

    <div class="flip-box"><div class="flip-box-inner">
        <div class="flip-box-front"><h2>Front Side</h2></div>
        <div class="flip-box-back"><h2>Back Side</h2></div>
    </div></div>
    <div class="flip-box"><div class="flip-box-inner">
        <div class="flip-box-front"><h2>Front Side</h2></div>
        <div class="flip-box-back"><h2>Back Side</h2></div>
    </div></div>
    <div class="flip-box"><div class="flip-box-inner">
        <div class="flip-box-front"><h2>Front Side</h2></div>
        <div class="flip-box-back"><h2>Back Side</h2></div>
    </div></div>
    <div class="flip-box"><div class="flip-box-inner">
        <div class="flip-box-front"><h2>Front Side</h2></div>
        <div class="flip-box-back"><h2>Back Side</h2></div>
    </div></div>
    <div class="flip-box"><div class="flip-box-inner">
        <div class="flip-box-front"><h2>Front Side</h2></div>
        <div class="flip-box-back"><h2>Back Side</h2></div>
    </div></div>
    <div class="flip-box"><div class="flip-box-inner">
        <div class="flip-box-front"><h2>Front Side</h2></div>
        <div class="flip-box-back"><h2>Back Side</h2></div>
    </div></div>
    <div class="flip-box"><div class="flip-box-inner">
        <div class="flip-box-front"><h2>Front Side</h2></div>
        <div class="flip-box-back"><h2>Back Side</h2></div>
    </div></div>
    <div class="flip-box"><div class="flip-box-inner">
        <div class="flip-box-front"><h2>Front Side</h2></div>
        <div class="flip-box-back"><h2>Back Side</h2></div>
    </div></div>
    <div class="flip-box"><div class="flip-box-inner">
        <div class="flip-box-front"><h2>Front Side</h2></div>
        <div class="flip-box-back"><h2>Back Side</h2></div>
    </div></div>
    <div class="flip-box"><div class="flip-box-inner">
        <div class="flip-box-front"><h2>Front Side</h2></div>
        <div class="flip-box-back"><h2>Back Side</h2></div>
    </div></div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```